# Relative pronouns part of speech

Tags: relative-pronouns, parts-of-speech

”Have you eaten all the cake THAT I made yesterday?”

”That” in this sentence is a relative pronoun that introduces the relative clause (I made yesterday), if I’m not mistaken. But what part of speech is ”that”? In dictionaries I find it under ”conjunctions”; is this correct? Are relative pronouns conjunctions and not pronouns?

Comment: Relative "that" is actually a subordinator, the same one that introduces declarative content clauses.

Comment: 'Subordinator' is its part of speech. In traditional grammar it's called a subordinating conjunction. Note that "that" is definitely not a relative pronoun: see my answer and that of user178049

Answer (score 3):

Traditionally it is analyzed as a relative pronoun (a subclass of **noun**). However, it is now considered a subordinator.

> Traditional grammar analyses the *that* which introduces relative clauses as a relative pronoun, comparable to *which* and *who*, but we believe that there is a good case for identifying it with the subordinator *that* which introduces declarative content clauses (Huddleston & Pullum, 2002: 1056).

This classification is based on four reasons, one of which is the lack of upward percolation. "Which", for example, allows a preposition to be fronted; this is called 'upward percolation' : eg. "This is the knife [with which I cut it]".

With the subordinator "that", this is clearly impossible; hence, the ungrammaticality of *"This is the knife [with that I cut it].

Note also that relative pronouns "which" and "who" inflect for the genitive case ("whose"), and the subordinator "that" does not.

Answer (score 3):

> *Have you eaten all the cake* [*THAT I made ___ yesterday*?]

"That" is not a relative pronoun but a subordinator. https://simple.wiktionary.org/wiki/that

It's the same subordinator that introduces declarative content clauses, as in *Ed told me that he had passed his exam*.

There are a number of reasons why it's not a pronoun, one of which is that it has no genitive form and it never occurs as complement of a preposition.

For example, *the patients to whom the letter was sent* is grammatical but **the patients to that the letter was sent* is of course not.